# Want to verify character count of textbox

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to validate the character count of a text field using TestNG, & I am not getting how to do so.

Here's my code what I have done, where upper limit is 50:-

[image]

I know I am doing something wrong but unable to understand what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting a text of length 51.  If you wanted to insert a text of length 50, change the <= to <.  Then your first if i.e if (n==50) would pass.

However, if what you are trying to validate whether your textfield can autotruncate a higher length string to 50, then, it might be that it is not behaving correctly since the char length is obviously not 50 so either it is truncating more or it is not truncating less, in which case it is a valid failure and should be taken up as a bug to the dev owner.